# How Do I Remove The Meta-data from txt file (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, metadata

I am needing to remove the meta-data from a text file on my computer how would i go about doing this, what software would i use, preferably freeware

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Open file Properties in Windows Explorer for Your file. Click Details tab. Click "Remove Properties and Personal information". Now choose to "Remove the following properties from this file", select which metadata to remove, press OK.

Method 2: Copy Your file to a filesystem which does not support metadata, like FAT32. Copy it back, metadata gone.